# Entity Framework 6.1 медленный первый запрос

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

Проблема далеко не уникальная, и есть много вопросов с ответами, в том числе и на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) по этому поводу, НО! почему-то, данные решения не помогают.

Что было сделано: Из [статьи](https://www.fusonic.net/developers/2014/07/09/3-steps-for-fast-entity-framework-6-1-code-first-startup-performance/) были опробованы 2 последних пункта  Interactive Pregenerated Views for Entity Framework 6 и Generate pre-compiled version of entityframework using n-gen to avoid jitting. Но в случае с Pregenerated Views разницы не заметил, хотя и судя по документации, должен появиться xml файл со схемой либо таблица в БД (если настройка на хранение в БД), но ничего такого не было, видно криво как так применено. Тоже самое с пунктом 2 `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen install EntityFramework.dll` - никакой разницы.

Запросы к сервису выполняются следующим образом:

```
    ServiceReference.ServiceClient svc = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient
    svc.GetDataCompleted()+=(s,ea)=>
    {
        ea.Result;
    };
    svc.GetData(parameters);
    svc.CloseAsync();
```

Запросы к БД элементарны, вида

```
    context = new context();
    var data = (from d in context.procedure(parameters) select d).ToList();
    return data;
```

Как раз .ToList() в первый запрос тратит максимальное время, т.е. порядка 7 сек.

.AsNoTracking()

.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Не помогают.

Возможно кто то пробовал использовать советы по ссылке выше по "ускорению" EF в связке с WCF? Подскажите как это сделать? 
Возможно, с WCF вообще есть какая то своя особенность?

Спасибо!

Comment: Проверьте под профайлером. у самого EF тоже есть проблемы с холодным стартом - например, долгая верификация миграций. или тормоза при построении планов. Заодно загляните в логи IIS, и проверьте - на серверной стороне тормозит, или на клиентской. пока по описанию нереально угадать, где именно и что тормозит

Comment: В общем, проблема все же в EF. Измерил запросы данных, получилась такая картина: 3 запроса, и разные этапы выполнения Data query: 1814,5673ms. ToList operation time: 8,9109 DateOperation: 13.10.2015 5:45:52
Data query: 1160,6373ms. ToList operation time: 0,1455 DateOperation: 13.10.2015 5:45:58
Data query: 1103,9561ms. ToList operation time: 0,1277DateOperation: 13.10.2015 5:46:07 Как видно, на первом запросе операция ToList занимает практически 9 секунд! Последующие уже намного легче. Как избежать этой первой 9 секундной задержки?

Comment: Посмотрите http://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/2014/07/09/three-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-first-query-performance/ и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423838/entity-framework-very-slow-to-load-for-first-time-after-every-compilation. И обновите вопрос, выбросив все, что не имеет отношения к проблеме (упоминания WCF, IIS и прочее). Уточните (прямо в вопросе), что именно у вас в EF используется - Code First / Db First, используются ли миграци - в них тормозят разные вещи. И все-таки пройдитесь профайлером.

Comment: все-таки возьмите профайлер - хотя бы триал dotTrace. без него вам никто нормальный ответ не даст - будут сплошные гадания.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить в класс вашего контекста статический конструктор со следующим содержанием:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ВашКонтекст>(null);
```

Это отключит действия, предпринимаемые EF для инициализации соединения с БД.

Если вы используете подход Database First - эта строчка будет необходимой и достаточной.

Но если вы используете подходы Model First или Code First - после добавления такой строчки база данных перестанет создаваться автоматически. Если автоматическое разворачивание БД является частью бизнес-логики вашего приложения, то *вместо* обнуления стратегии инициализации лучше пойти по альтернативному пути - явно пнуть инициализацию EF во время старта приложения. Это делается следующим кодом:

```
using (var ctx = new ВашКонтекст())
{
    ctx.Database.Initialize();
}
```

Во всех остальных случаях я бы рекомендовал создание БД вынести в отдельную утилиту примерно следующего содержания:

```
var initializer = new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ВашКонтекст>(); // Или любая другая стратегия инициалоизации
using (var ctx = new ВашКонтекст())
{
    initializer.Initialize(ctx);
}
```

PS Слово "попробуйте" в начале ответа означает, что надо взять и попробовать. Этот ответ может как помочь, так и нет в зависимости от тучи самых разных факторов. Начинать пробовать надо всегда с той строчки кода, которая приведена первой. Остальная часть ответа актуально только в том случае, если эта строчка кода и правда поможет.

Comment: Суть в том, что все обращения к БД в отдельной библиотеке APP_DAL.dll, которая расположена на IIS и является частью WCF сервиса. Т.е. каждый запрос - отдельное using(Context = new Context()){ ... }. Как бы нету явного старта программы. :(

Comment: Тогда убирайте стратегию инициализации (устанавливайте ее в null). Развертывать БД прямо из ASP.NET-приложения - не лучшая идея по многим причинам.

Comment: Для EF используется database first подход. Database.Initialize() не используется в коде нигде. Приложение Silverlight.

Comment: При чем тут `Database.Initialize()`? Прочитайте мой ответ еще раз.

Comment: @PavelMayorov инициализация базы применима только для CodeFirst - и тормозить она может только при нем. У топикастера - DB First. Прочитайте его коммент еще раз.

Comment: @PashaPash, может он и использует DB First подход - но контекст-то у него явно наследник DbContext! И EF в любом случае будет пытаться выполнить стратегию инициализации по умолчению, которая в том числе сравнивает модель контекста с моделью БД в целях поиска несовместимостей.

Comment: @PavelMayorov так распишите свое предположение подробно, а не ограничивайтесь ссылкой вникуда, на статью, которая скорее всего неприменима. Напишите как подтвердить, что это именно инициализация схемы тормозит. Что именно значит "если позволяет логика". Сейчас ваш ответ вообще никак не помогает решить проблему.

Comment: @PashaPash, я предложил автору вопроса добавить одну простую строчку и посмотреть, ускорит это первый запрос или нет. Что в этом ответе вообще непонятного? Как можно писать полный и развернутый ответ, когда источник проблемы неясен?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не надо писать полный и развернутый ответ, когда источник не ясен. нужно помочь топикастеру локализовать проблему - взять профайлер и померять. а не предлагать ему ставить костыли наугад.

Comment: @PashaPash, большинство профайлеров ничего интереснее ToList() не показывают, уже проверено.

Comment: @PavelMayorov странно, у меня профайлер в EF вполне показывал тормоза при валидации миграций. может профайлер у вас был ненастоящий? :) кстати, вопрос висел тут месяц, пока топикастер смог вообще понять, что это именно EF. думаю, возьми он профайлер - месяц бы не понадобился.

Comment: @PashaPash, без специалиста по внутренностям EF можно пару недель профилировать, но так и не увидеть тормоза при валидации миграций... Проверить всевозможные костыли - куда быстрее. Хотя проверять костыли с профайлером - лучше чем без него, безусловно.

Comment: Коллеги! Database.SetInitializer<ВашКонтекст>(null); не помогает. Месяц висит обращение, потому что не всегда удается проводить много времени над этой проблемой, есть другие задачи, более приоритетные. Тут вопрос производительности (причем не критичный, но лично меня раздражающий), а есть более приоритетные функциональные проблемы. Попробую dotTrace.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, по поводу профайлера.

Профилировать одновременно работу WCF, ASP.NET и EF, конечно же можно - и иногда даже нужно, но это сложно. Поскольку сейчас уже ясно, что тормозит именно EF, а не что-то другое - то и профилировать надо только EF.

Начать лучше всего с создания отдельного консольного приложения, ссылающегося на основную библиотеку.

Для начала, подойдет простой код вроде такого:

```
using (var ctx = new ВашКонтекст())
{
    ctx.ЛюбаяТаблица.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id = 0);
}
```

Поскольку мы замеряем время именно холодного старта EF - сам запрос можно брать любой. Желательно такой, который вернет 0 записей.

Теперь можно начинать профилировать этот код...

Comment: В общем, я теперь вообще не знаю куда копать. Сделал консольное приложение, подключил проект, который работает с БД. В консольном приложении 2 строки, эмулирующие точно такие же запросы к БД, как я делал через интерфейс. Получаются вполне себе безобидные цифры, да первый запрос выполняется дольше 1700ms против 1000ms на втором, но это не те порядки, чтоб было до этого. Самое главное, что сейчас замеряя длительность запросов через WCF время получается схожее с консольным приложением. :(

Comment: dotTrace показывает, что большую часть времени занимает System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(). Как полный trace выложить не совсем понятно.

Comment: Подскажите, как выловить проблему? Как найти узкое место в связке IIS + WCF + EF? Приложение Silverlight. Или теперь нужная снова старая тема? (

Comment: @ЮрийАлексеев, видимо, да...